# How to use mapbox.js as a background so that html content and Navbar stay visible on top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mapbox

I am trying to incorporate MapBox.js into a Bootstrap 3 website. The idea is to use a map as a background of a row that uses the whole width of the website and to display the html-content on top of that. In order to push MapBox.js to the back, I assigned it a z-value of -1.

The problem now is that the fixed navbar is not working properly in Chrome any longer. The links cannot be hovered and seem to scroll behind the MapBox, although navbar has a generic z-value of 1030. I already tried to increase the z-value in the following way, but nothing is working: .

```
navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

The mapbox-css can be found here: http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.5.2/mapbox.css

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row"> Other Section</div>


<!-- Map Start -->
<div class="row" >    
    <div  id="map"></div>

    <div class="container" id="section1-container">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <br />
            <br />

            <h1 class="text-center">Ipusm Lorum.</h1>

            <br />
            <br />

        </div>

        <div class="row text-center">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <address>
                    <strong><abbr title="Telefono">T:</abbr> 777777777</strong
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <address>
                    <strong><abbr title="Mail">M:</abbr> <a href="mailto:#">info@eample.com</a></strong
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <address>
                    <strong><abbr title="Dirrecion">D:</abbr> any street</strong
                </address>
            </div>


            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />


        </div>


    </div>

<!-- Map End -->
</div>
```

Other Section

**CSS**

```
#section1-container {

    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#map { 
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 500px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.5.2/mapbox.js"></script>

     <script>
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y', {
        scrollWheelZoom: false,
        zoomControl: false})
        .setView([40, -74.50], 9);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push more content below, you'll want to just contain everything in a block. The map position absolutes to its container, which in this case is the body. By giving it a wrapper div to contain it, you can continue with more content down the page.

I've updated @anpsmn's jsfiddle:

```
<div id="section1-wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section2-wrapper" class="wrapper">
    ...
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2wj7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove two ids given to the div, ids must be unique.

```
<div  id="map" class="row" id="section1-wrapper">
```

Give z-index for both sections such that `#map` gets a lower value than the `#section-container`

```
#map {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 0
}
#section1-container {
    background-color:black;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/CB3Tp/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as intended. The map needs to be contained within a row-container, because there are other sections above and below, i.e. the map shouldn't be top:0 and bottom:0. Using the z-values, I get problems in Chrome with the fixed navbar (z-index: 1030), which is partly disappearing when scrolling and navbar-hovering is not working.